# Android file uploading using Ion, but upload file was empty

Tags: android, file-upload, android-ion

My uploading with Ion returned success.  But uploaded file was empty.
As packet dump from wireshark, Ion didn't send file contents.

What did I mistake?

Here are my codes.

`MyFragment.java`

```
Ion.with(getContext())
        .load(uploadUrl)
        .uploadProgressHandler(new ProgressCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(long downloaded, long total) {
                LOG.debug("" + downloaded + " / " + total);
            }
        })
        .setMultipartFile("file", new File(currentPhotoPath))
        .asJsonObject()
        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                String msg;
                if (e != null) {
                    LOG.error("upload failed:", e);
                } else {
                    LOG.info("upload completed: {}", result.toString());
                }
        });
```

I'm using android studio 3.0 and LG G version 5.0.

`build.gradle`
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "kr.co.digitalpie.dansok"
    minSdkVersion 17  //Android 4.2 Jelly Bean
    targetSdkVersion 26 
    versionCode 55
    versionName "4.0.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
dependencies {
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    ...
```

`Whireshark packet dump`

[image]

From whireshark, Ion didn't send file correctly.
So I checked my devices local photo was valid.
Uploading photo was located in `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/DigitalPie/P_20171214_141206_2058037049.jpg`, and it's size was 350Kbytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It caused by totally my silly mistake.
Before starting uploading my another asynctask tried to compress it, but failed.  Because of it, compressed image was empty.

I found out my mistake  by logging as below.

```
LOG.info("uploading filesize: " + currentPhotoPath.getSize());
Ion.with(getContext())
 ...
```

The log said `uploading filesize: 0`.

Hope my silly mistake to help someone.